# My implementation wont let me batch more than 4 transfer calls

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, kusama, acala, txwrapper

My implementation wont let me batch more than 4 transfers. Am I doing something wrong?

I know the code is a bit complex because its normally not in one func  but i has to be in this way. I am suprised that it wont work for more than 4 transfers. Its a bit odd to me tbh.

Can someone please help me asap? Thanks.

Error i am getting : `1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction has a bad signature`

Note: If i use transfer and batchAll it gives `-32603: Internal error`,
if i use transfer and batch it gives the same invalid Signature error

```rust
    const specVersion = getSpecVersion();
    const transactionVersion = getTransactionVersion();
    const specName: any = getSpecName();
    const chainName = getChainName();

    [block, metadataRpc] = await Promise.all([
      rawBlock = await getBlock(blockHash),
      metadataRpc = getMetaDataRpc(),
     ]);

    const registry = this.getRegistry({
      chainName,
      specName,
      specVersion,
      metadataRpc,
      asCallsOnlyArg: true,
    });

    const account = getAccount(publicKey);

    const transferArgs = []
    // logic that converts transfers to {dest, value} and pushes them to transferArgs

  const batchTransferMethods = transferArgs.map((args) => {
    const txInfo = methods.balances.transferKeepAlive(
      args,
      {
        address: account.address,
        blockHash,
        blockNumber,
        eraPeriod,
        genesisHash,
        metadataRpc,
        nonce,
        specVersion,
        tip,
        transactionVersion,
      },
      {
        metadataRpc,
        registry,
      },
    );

    return txInfo.method;
  });


  const unsigned = methods.utility.batchAll(
    {
      calls: batchTransferMethods,
    },
    {
      address: account.address,
      blockHash,
      blockNumber,
      eraPeriod,
      genesisHash,
      metadataRpc,
      nonce,
      tip,
      transactionVersion,
    },
    {
      metadataRpc,
      registry,
    },
  );

   
  const extrinsicPayload = registry.createType('ExtrinsicPayload', unsigned, {
    version: unsigned.version,
  });

  const extrinsicPayloadU8a = extrinsicPayload.toU8a({ method: true });

  const dataToSign = Buffer.from(registry.hash(extrinsicPayloadU8a)).toString(
    'hex',
  );


  // signing operation and logic

  const signedTransaction = construct.signedTx(
      unsigned,
      signatureWithPrefix,
      {
        metadataRpc,
        registry,
      },
   );

  const signedTransaction = transaction({ transactionToSubmit });

    let response: {
      events: EventRecord[];
      status: ExtrinsicStatus;
      txHash: Hash;
    };

  let blockNumber: string, signedBlock: SignedBlock;
  try {
      response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        signedTransaction
          .send(({ events = [], status, txHash }) => {
            if (status.isFinalized) {
              resolve({ events, status, txHash });
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
      });

      signedBlock = await getBlock(response.status.asFinalized.toHex());
      blockNumber = signedBlock.block.header.number.toString();

      response.events.forEach(({ event }) => {
        if (this.api.events.system.ExtrinsicFailed.is(event)) {
          // extract the data for this event
          const [dispatchError] = event.data;
          let errorInfo: string;

          // decode the error
          if (dispatchError.isModule) {
            const decoded = this.api.registry.findMetaError(
              dispatchError.asModule,
            );

            errorInfo = `${decoded.section}.${decoded.name}`;
          } else {
            // Other, CannotLookup, BadOrigin, no extra info
            errorInfo = dispatchError.toString();
          }

          throw new BadRequestException(
            `Transaction has been reverted. transactionHash: ${blockNumber}-${
              (response.events[0].phase.toJSON() as any).applyExtrinsic
            } , ExtrinsicFailed:: ${errorInfo} `,
          );
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw new BroadcastFailedError(error.message);
    }
```